# get value of Dynamic select option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have more than one select option, i want to make whenever i change my select option, input field will be filled with data-place of my select option

This a few dynamic select option

```js
$(function() {
     // Remove button click
     $(document).on(
         'click',
         '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="remove"]',
         function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             $(this).closest('.form-inline').remove();
         }
     );
     // Add button click
     $(document).on(
         'click',
         '[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="add"]',
         function(e) {
             e.preventDefault();
             var container = $(this).closest('[data-role="dynamic-fields"]');
             new_field_group = container.children().filter('.form-inline:first-child').clone();
             new_field_group.find('input').each(function(){
                 $(this).val('');
             });
             container.append(new_field_group);
         }
     );

 });

$('.id_penumpang').on('change',function(){
  value = $(this).attr("data-id")
  place = $(this).find(':selected').attr('data-place')
  console.log(place)
})
```

```css
[data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline + .form-inline {
     margin-top: 0.5em;
 }

 [data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline [data-role="add"] {
     display: none;
 }

 [data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline:last-child [data-role="add"] {
     display: inline-block;
 }

 [data-role="dynamic-fields"] > .form-inline:last-child [data-role="remove"] {
     display: none;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="dynamic-fields">
<!-- /div.form-inline -->
<div class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
 <select required="" class="form-control tink id_penumpang" name="id_penumpang[]" id="id_penumpang"><option value="110" data-id="110" data-place="Ds. Supono No. 929">Elvina Maryadi</option><option value="130" data-id="130" data-place="Ds. Wahidin No. 679">Carla Irawan</option><option value="131" data-id="131" data-place="Jln. Perintis Kemerdekaan No. 903">Cinta Putra</option><option value="150" data-id="150" data-place="Jr. Reksoninten No. 355">Dewi Gunarto</option><option value="157" data-id="157" data-place="Ds. Pasir Koja No. 481">Harjasa Adriansyah</option><option value="161" data-id="161" data-place="Jr. Sukabumi No. 142">Darsirah Laksita</option><option value="166" data-id="166" data-place="Ki. Abdul No. 288">Ellis Wijaya</option><option value="168" data-id="168" data-place="Kpg. Bakaru No. 622">Syahrini Mandasari</option><option value="171" data-id="171" data-place="Psr. Babakan No. 763">Harjo Farida</option><option value="183" data-id="183" data-place="Ki. Bass No. 823">Gabriella Namaga</option><option value="186" data-id="186" data-place="Ki. Soekarno Hatta No. 617">Shakila Mustofa</option><option value="187" data-id="187" data-place="Ki. Bakit  No. 674">Rini Suryatmi</option><option value="189" data-id="189" data-place="Gg. Laksamana No. 672">Bahuraksa Usamah</option><option value="193" data-id="193" data-place="Ds. Basoka Raya No. 64">Fitriani Padmasari</option></select>
</div>
<span>-</span>
<div class="form-group info-alamat">
    <input required="" type="text" name="alamat[]" class="form-control" id="field-value" placeholder="Ketik alamat penumpang ...">
</div>
<button class="btn btn-danger" data-role="remove">
    remove</span>
</button>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-role="add">
    add</span>
</button>
</div></div>
```

How can i place my data-place to my input field ?

Can anyone give me a solution what should I change so that the code I create works?

Comment: Let me understand this. You would like your input be filled with the selected options data-place?

Comment: yes, attribute data-place

Answer (score 0):

**NOTE: this is just a basic example for the method**

I could provide you a basic example for the method you are looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/rg3ovpq5/

Basicly, when you change the selected `option` in the `select`, your input will have the option's `data-place` value

HTML:

```
<select id="select">
  <option data-place="option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option data-place="option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option data-place="option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="result">
```

JQuery:

```
$('body').on('change', '#select', function(){
    $('[name="result"]').val($('#select option:selected').data("place"));
});
```

```js
$('body').on('change', '#select', function(){
        $('[name="result"]').val($('#select option:selected').data("place"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select">
  <option data-place="option 1">Option 1</option>
  <option data-place="option 2">Option 2</option>
  <option data-place="option 3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<input type="text" name="result">
```

Comment: thanks for suggest, but if it's just like that I can already do it